# AWS Lambda how to access on-premise sql server

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-vpc

Our local server is connected to AWS via VPN. I can telnet our on-premise sql server in AWS EC2, but I can't connect to the sql server in Lambda function, always timeout. The EC2 and Lambda function are in same VPC. Did I miss something?

Comment: The db server didn't block any clients

Comment: Routing tables attached to Subnet, Are Ec2 and Lambda launched in the same Subnet and using the same routing table ? Assuming it's a AWS VPN, not from Ec2 to your on premise using openswan etc.

Comment: yes, it's AWS VPN. I have checked, same subnet and routing table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to SQL SERVER 2008 SP3 from RTM, problem solved.